# How to avoid displaying duplicated values or overwrite duplicated values in php foreach loop in table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently working on codeigniter. I want to display a value that is not been duplicated or overwrite a duplicated value from mysql database into the datatable of php foreach loop.

Here is the table code:

```
    <table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table" id="myTable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="headings">
                                            <th>Employee No.</th>
                                            <th>Username</th>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Status</th> 
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php 
                                        foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee){?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $employee->empnum; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $employee->username; ?></td> 
                                            <td><?php echo $employee->name; ?> <?php echo $employee->lastname; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php 
                                            if ($employee->hasClockOut==1){
                                                echo '<a class="label label-danger">Inactive</a>';
                                            }else {
                                                echo '<a class="label label-success">Active</a>';
                                            }
                                            ?></td> 
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: why dont you only select unique values, in your query

Comment: It doesn't work as well.

Comment: An explanation of your data and expected results might help clarify your needs and get you a more accurate answer. "doesn't work" really explains little.

Comment: You have facebook? So that I can send you a picture of my datatable.

Comment: Make `empnum` Unique so that no duplicates exist in table.I think your table is having duplicate records thats why you are getting duplicate rows after query.either you use `group_by` or assign unique key to empnum.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use -

$EMPLOYEES = array_unique($EMPLOYEES);

Comment: Well, you'll need to post the contents of $EMPLOYEES and a bit more bout what you want to do as its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th>Employee No.</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $emp='';
        foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee){ 
        if($emp!=$employee->username){ # if username contain duplicate values
       ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $employee->empnum; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee->username; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $employee->name; ?> <?php echo $employee->lastname; ?></td>
            <td><?php 
            if ($employee->hasClockOut==1){
                echo '<a class="label label-danger">Inactive</a>';
            }else {
                echo '<a class="label label-success">Active</a>';
            }
            ?></td> 
        </tr>
        <?php }$emp=$employee->username;} ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```